# get error throwing php script name inside class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using Bennett Stone php wrapper class for mysqli operations. class is working fine without any issues. There is a function inside it (shared below) which sends an email to administrator for any kind of mysqli errors.

**Issue**

There are 100's of scripts using this class, I am not able to find out which script thrown any particular error.

**What i want**

I want to get the full path of error originating script inside class from where query originated. for example, test.php contains query & post execution if any error comes out then i want complete path of test.php inside error handling function along with error details (shared below).

**What i can do**

Class modification I can do by my own

I am getting details like this:

```
Error at 2016-08-23 05:44:18:
Query: SELECT email FROM users WHERE 
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

**Error handling function**

```
public function log_db_errors( $error, $query )
{
    $message = '<p>Error at '. date('Y-m-d H:i:s').':</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Query: '. htmlentities( $query ).'<br />';
    $message .= 'Error: ' . $error;
    $message .= '</p>';

    if( defined( 'SEND_ERRORS_TO' ) )
    {
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: Admin <'.SEND_ERRORS_TO.'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: systems<noreply@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'.com>' . "\r\n";

        mail( SEND_ERRORS_TO, 'Database Error', $message, $headers );   
    }
    else
    {
        trigger_error( $message );
    }

    if( !defined( 'DISPLAY_DEBUG' ) || ( defined( 'DISPLAY_DEBUG' ) && DISPLAY_DEBUG ) )
    {
        echo $message;   
    }
}
```

Comment: [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) might help you.

Comment: As @JonStirling states - [Debug Backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) is what you want to be exploring here

Comment: @Martin as I stated below, exceptions in PHP provide a stack trace by default, thus there is no need to write any code by hand.

Comment: The key qualifier there is "exceptions". If the OP is *not* using exceptions (as it appears) then [debug backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) covers their needs.  @YourCommonSense

Comment: Thanks @Jon - finally your suggestion worked as per requirement. I used http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php#47644 function inside log_db_errors message & i got what i was looking for. Thanks for your help. It took me 9 hours to get this working :-)

Answer (score 2):

Put these lines somewhere above all your codes:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors',     1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

and you will have every error logged with a **stack trace**. While all this bushy "log_db_errors" stuff will be thrown away.

the problem solved.

NB. This wrapper class is just terrible. Utilizes almost every bad practice ever exists.

Comment: class do contains this -- mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT ); -- inside  -- public function __construct(). do you want me to add MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR along with MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT?. i cannot test on live server hence i just want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the key point to do it the way it is written in my answer. You may also want to add  `ini_set('display_errors',0);` to be sure that nothing will be written in the browswer

Comment: I have added intentionally a column in query which doesn't exists in a table. I should get an error now. but i am not receiving any email with error like i was getting before. I placed the complete code in public function_construct(); Did i do something wrong?

Comment: apart from that as per my knowledge variable $error mentioned inside log_db_errors function should contain stack trace. Am i wrong?

Comment: You won't get any error by email anymore. As I said, all errors will be **logged now**, in the error log file.

Comment: just checked & it's showing errors in error log file. But with this i have to check error log of multiple folders :-(. can i get this stack trace on email using this log_db_errors function somehow ?

Comment: yes, but you will need to write an exception wrapper for that.  besides, you can tall PHP to use a single log file for all projects. By the way, do you care for whatever errors beside  db errors?

Comment: yes, i do care for other errors as well. But my issue is that i don't have time to check error logs until i get some notifications due to time issues. I was looking some function which tells me that something happened on this point & primarily db error happens so i chose this class for getting email notifications as & when error occurred at any script. moreover with error logs i won't get any notification if something new added. if there is some method to get email for every new entry in error log then pls tell me. this will save my day !!

Comment: you can write a simple error handler using http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php and make it send you emails

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is catching exception and edit error message, using some `magic php const` in it : [PHP: Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Example, in your class, around the query :

```
try {
    // your query
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // launch your log_db_errors() function, with some of const, like __CLASS__, __LINE__, etc :
    $error = '[' . __FILE__ . '][' . __CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__ . '][' . __LINE__ . '] : ' . $e->getMessage();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: 1. There is no point in catching an exception that was never thrown. 2. All this information already exists inside the exception, thus there is no point in writing it by hand. 3. catching exceptions right in place is a terrible practice, perverting the whole idea of exceptions mechanism.